# OS X Share Extension : killed when too long upload/task

Tags: macos, http, swift, osx-yosemite

I'm currently building a Share extension for OS X Yosemite in Swift. This permits to integrate any web service to the system and lets the user send links or photos in two clicks.

I already have an implementation for images, and it works for small images. The thing is, when the picture is too large, OS X kills the extension before the upload is finished ("plugin interrupted"), surely because it considers that it's too long. I'm using the [SwiftHTTP library](https://github.com/daltoniam/SwiftHTTP) for performing my requests.

On the [Apple documentation about extensions](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/ExtensibilityPG/ExtensionOverview.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014214-CH2-SW6), there is a loose statement saying that the extension can't "Perform long-running background tasks", without precision.

Does someone know more about this restriction ? And maybe propose me a workaround ?

Best regards,

François

Comment: No one has a clue for this ? :(